# How does Magento 2 work with CSS grunt-autoprefixer

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, less-compilation

From looking at a fresh install of Magento 2 (v2.1.8) I see from their `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` files that Magento is using [grunt-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-autoprefixer)

1. This is great, CSS autoprefixers are really useful. But I can't see how to use it with Magento's Gruntfile, does anyone have an idea how it works?
2. Also, how would this work in production mode on a live environment?  Doesn't Magento2 use use a PHP LESS compiler in production mode, while Grunt is just used for developing with.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
/**
 * Production preparation task.
 */
prod: function (component) {
    var tasks = [
        'less',
        'autoprefixer',
        'cssmin',
        'usebanner'
    ]
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "glob": "^5.0.14",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
```

I ran `grunt autoprefixer` and it does not seem to work either.

```
$ grunt autoprefixer
Running "autoprefixer:setup" (autoprefixer) task
Autoprefixer's process() method is deprecated and will removed in next major release. Use postcss([autoprefixer]).process() instead
File setup/pub/styles/setup.css created.

Running "autoprefixer:updater" (autoprefixer) task
Warning: No source files were found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2017-10-29 11:12:01 UTC-0)
loading tasks               145ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 30%
loading grunt-autoprefixer  118ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 24%
autoprefixer:setup          216ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 45%
autoprefixer:updater          5ms  ▇▇ 1%
Total 485ms
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Customize `dev/tools/grunt/configs/autoprefixer.json` and run `grunt autoprefixer`.
2. You need to setup it manually in you the deployment pipeline, b/c there is no way to run Grunt tasks from Magento.

Comment: running `grunt autoprefixer` aborted with out completing with the message `Autoprefixer's process() method is deprecated and will removed in next major release. Use postcss([autoprefixer]).process() instead`.  Which suggests that Magento does not support auto-prefixing at all?

Comment: Even if Grunt was setup to run in the deployment pipeline, it would not be reliable, if an admin user cleared the CSS cache.

Comment: Also, how is it possible to set up a grunt task in a `.json` file?  Doesn't Grunt need to be set up in a `.js` file

Comment: 1. It works, that's just a deprecation warning. Few lines below you have an info about processed files.

Comment: 2. Cache dosen't remove files in `pub` themes directory, so it's 100% safe.

Comment: 3. I'm not a Grunt expert, but in works here. Maybe they use some plugin to make it possible.

Comment: can you post an example of your `dev/tools/grunt/configs/autoprefixer.json` file?

Comment: I'm not using Grunt, nor even LESS.

Comment: I ran `grunt autoprefixer` and it does not work, see my updated question

Comment: The warning is clear `No source files were found.`, you are trying to process a not existing file.

Comment: ok, so do you know where or how to specify which files to specify. `grunt less:luma` & `grunt less:mytheme` both work without any errors after following [these instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html).

Answer (score 5):

Please perform above changes, I hope it will work out well.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "author": "Vendor",
  "description": "Node modules dependencies for local development",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "(OSL-3.0 OR AFL-3.0)",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/magento/magento2.git"
  },
  "homepage": "http://magento.com/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.14",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-banner": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-eslint": "17.3.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "grunt-jscs": "2.2.0",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-replace": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-styledocco": "^0.1.4",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "^0.2.3",
    "grunt-text-replace": "^0.4.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^4.0.1",
    "load-grunt-config": "^0.16.0",
    "morgan": "^1.5.0",
    "node-minify": "^1.0.1",
    "path": "^0.11.14",
    "serve-static": "^1.7.1",
    "strip-json-comments": "^1.0.2",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

**postcss.js**

```
/**
 * PostCSS autoprefixer initialisation
 *
 * Docs: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer
 * Config: dev/tools/grunt/configs/postcss.json
 * Usage: grunt autoprefixer:themename [--verbose] [--debug]
 * To do: load src from themes.js
 *
 * @param grunt
 */

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');

    grunt.registerTask('autoprefixer', function (target) {
        var currentTarget = target || 'dist';

        /*** configuration tweaks ***/
        var config = grunt.config.get('postcss');

        // set 'processors' options (not possible to set function in json config)
        config['options'].processors = [require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions']})];

        // apply theme source and destination dynamically
        if (target) {
            config[target] = {
                src: ['pub/static/frontend/*/'+target+'/*/css/*.css']
            };
        }
        grunt.config.set('postcss', config);

        grunt.option('force', true);
        grunt.task.run('postcss:'+currentTarget);
    });
};
```

**postcss.json**

```
{
    "options": {
        "map": true
    },
    "dist": {
      "src": ["pub/static/frontend/*/*/*/css/*.css"]
    }
}
```

After setup above files, run `grunt autoprefixer`

Comment: You should submit this as a PR to the core, replacing current outdated setup

Answer (score 0):

To be really clear for everyone:
postcss.js & postcss.json - go in /dev/tools/grunt/configs
package.json - in the website root - just check it includes autoprefixer under devDependencies

Once done run exec / less / watch / setup in the usual way.

Then access your website in a browser to create the CSS cache files.

then, run:
grunt autoprefixer

this will check the resulting css files and add -webkit- and other browser support

This is a good fix for development but I have not found a way to use this in production.